# Recursive sequence $x_n = \sqrt{2}$, $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2x_n}$

Tags: python, math, sequence

How would I create a script it in python late the values from the recursive sequence:

[$x_1 = \sqrt{2}$, $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2x_n}$ http://www.sciweavers.org/upload/Tex2Img_1392861864/render.png](http://www.sciweavers.org/upload/Tex2Img_1392861864/render.png)

Comment: you mean `x_0=sqrt(2)`?

Comment: Why is my latex not formatting?

Comment: It should be $x_1 = sqrt{2}$

Comment: Unlike math.stackexchange.com, SO does not render latex. I pasted an image using http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor.

Comment: This question is basic enough that you should probably just go through the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). As it is, it's too close to "write me the code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X = [sqrt(2)]
for i in range(1,10):
    X.append(sqrt(2*X[i-1]))
```

Comment: Depending on the use, you might want a generator: `x = sqrt(2); while True: yield x; x = sqrt(2 * x);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slow solution. Assuming n is >=1

```
import math
def recursive(n):
    if n = 1:
        math.sqrt(2)
    return math.sqrt(2*recursive(n-1))
```